# MSAL : AADB2C90146 : 'Openid profile' provided in request specifies more than one resource for an access token, which is not supported'

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

When trying to use

```
this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(scopes)...
```

I have multiple scopes I am passing in although I receive the error :

> AADB2C90146 : The scope 'https://xxx.onmicrosoft.com/xxx/user_impersonation https://xxx.onmicrosoft.com/xxx/user_impersonation openid profile' provided in request specifies more than one resource for an access token, which is not supported.

How am I able to silently get a new token using the MSAL.js library for multiple scopes? I was able to do so initially with the

```
 this.clientApplication.loginRedirect(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes);
```

Is this possible at this time?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access tokens are tied to a resource.  If you specify multiple scopes that map to multiple resources, MSAL doesn't know which one to get an access token for since there's some ambiguity.

For example,

`Scope A.0`, `Scope A.1` belong to `Resource A`

`Scope B.0` belong to `Resource B`

Requests would need to be:

`// Access tokens for Resource A
acquireTokenSilent([Scope A.0, Scope A.1])`

`// Access tokens for Resource B
acquireTokenSilent([Scope B.0])`

Comment: Right, an access token (and id token) always has an *audience* that you can find in the `aud` claim. That identifies the service the token is meant for.

Comment: I am trying to use this method to get a acces token for a different scope that has been used in the call to acuireTokenAsync. However it keeps setting the scope in the result to the original scope. Not the one I just specified.

Comment: @TomEsendam can you reach out to me directly with your issue? My email is on my StackOverflow profile. It may be a bug.

Comment: @DanielDobalian I didn't see your response! I'll do that thanks.