# dotnet-core WebApp and multiple web api's access tokens using AzureB2C, MSAL

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, openid, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have setup authentication/authorization for WebApp and Api and its working fine. The problem is when I have to introduce additional Api's which will be called from WebAPP.

The limitation is that you cannot ask a token with scopes mixing Web apis in one call. This is a limitation of the service (AAD), not of the library.
you have to ask a token for https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/api1/read
and then you can acquire a token silently for https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/api2/read as those are two different APIS.
I learned more about this from [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362631/msal-aadb2c90146-openid-profile-provided-in-request-specifies-more-than-on#answer-49365888) and [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/550)

Since there is no full example other than couple of lines of code, I'm trying to find best way of implementing this solution.

Currently I have setup Authentication in Startup

```
 services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
 {
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 })

 services.AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options)).AddCookie();
```

AddAzureAdB2C is an customized extension method from [Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=azure%20b2c&type=&language=).

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdB2C(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdB2COptions> configureOptions)
{
    builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup>();
    builder.AddOpenIdConnect();
        return builder;
}

public class OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup : IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
{
    public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
    {
        options.ClientId = AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId;
        options.Authority = AzureAdB2COptions.Authority;
        options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { NameClaimType = "name" };

        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
        {
            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
            OnRemoteFailure = OnRemoteFailure,
            OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived
        };
    }

    public Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext context)
    {
        var defaultPolicy = AzureAdB2COptions.DefaultPolicy;
        if (context.Properties.Items.TryGetValue(AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty, out var policy) &&
                !policy.Equals(defaultPolicy))
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile;
            context.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
            context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.ToLower().Replace(defaultPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
                context.Properties.Items.Remove(AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AzureAdB2COptions.ApiUrl))
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.Scope += $" offline_access {AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes}";
            context.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

I guess the scope has to be set on this line for each API but this is part of pipeline.(in else if part of OnRedirectToIdentityProvide method above)

```
 context.ProtocolMessage.Scope += $" offline_access {AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes}";
```

Following are api client configuration

```
services.AddHttpClient<IApiClient1, ApiClient1>()
   .AddHttpMessageHandler<API1AccessTokenHandler>();

services.AddHttpClient<IApiClient2, ApiClient2>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<API2AccessTokenHandler>();
```

Following is the code for acquiring token silently for API1.

```
 public class API1AccessTokenHandler : DelegatingHandler
 {
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IConfidentialClientApplication publicClientApplication = null;
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the token with the specified scopes
            scopes = AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes.Split(' ');
            string signedInUserID = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

            publicClientApplication =  ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId)
                                                                            .WithRedirectUri(AzureAdB2COptions.RedirectUri)
                                                                            .WithClientSecret(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientSecret)
                                                                            .WithB2CAuthority(AzureAdB2COptions.Authority)
                                                                            .Build();

            new MSALStaticCache(signedInUserID, _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext).EnablePersistence(publicClientApplication.UserTokenCache);

            var accounts = await publicClientApplication.GetAccountsAsync();
            result = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
        }

        if (result.AccessToken== null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Following is the code for acquiring token silently for API2, API2AccessTokenHandler.

```
 public class API2AccessTokenHandler : DelegatingHandler
 {
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IConfidentialClientApplication publicClientApplication = null;
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the token with the specified scopes
            scopes = Constants.Api2Scopes.Split(' ');
            string signedInUserID = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

            publicClientApplication =  ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId)
                                                                            .WithRedirectUri(AzureAdB2COptions.RedirectUri)
                                                                            .WithClientSecret(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientSecret)
                                                                            .WithB2CAuthority(AzureAdB2COptions.Authority)
                                                                            .Build();

            new MSALStaticCache(signedInUserID, _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext).EnablePersistence(publicClientApplication.UserTokenCache);

            var accounts = await publicClientApplication.GetAccountsAsync();
            result = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
        }

        if (result.AccessToken== null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

1. Passing the scope while acquiring the token did not help. The token
   is always null.
2. The account always have scope for Api1 but not for
   Api2.
3. The scope of APi1 is added from the AzureB2COptions.ApiScope
   as part of the ServiceCollection pipeline code in Startup.cs

I guess having separate calls to Acquire token is not helping in case of Api2 because scope is being set for Api1 in Startup.cs.

Please provide your valuable suggestions along with code samples.

**UPDATE:**
I'm looking something similar to [WithExtraScopeToConsent](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-interactively#withextrascopetoconsent) which is designed for IPublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive. I need similar extension for ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder to be used for AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode

```
cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes.Split(' '), code)
   .WithExtraScopeToConsent(additionalScopeForAPi2)
   .ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: Try with the sample here. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi. You can use two different apis as the scope.

Comment: I have tried this it throws errors, you can have multiple scopes for same api not multiple scopes from different Apis. could you please provide an example or article using multiple scopes from different apis

Comment: @Mady did you find a solution? We have the same issue but in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can have multiple scopes for same api not multiple scopes from different Apis.

In [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi), we retrieve the token with the specified scopes.

```
// Retrieve the token with the specified scopes
                var scope = new string[] { api1_scope };

                IConfidentialClientApplication cca = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
                var accounts = await cca.GetAccountsAsync();
                AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilent(scope, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
                var accessToken=result.AccessToken;
```

You can get the accessToken with different api scope.

```
// Retrieve the token with the specified scopes
                var scope = new string[] { api2_scope };

                IConfidentialClientApplication cca = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
                var accounts = await cca.GetAccountsAsync();
                AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilent(scope, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
                var accessToken=result.AccessToken;
```

Comment: I'm already doing that please look API1AccessTokenHandler and API2AccessTokenHandler.